# Как в Laravel вовремя form request валидации задать значения которы будут использоваться в контроллере?

Tags: php, laravel

Есть запрос который проходит через form request class `OrderRequestStore` там используется custom rule `ValidOrderRequest` который проверяет  есть ли такие продукты с такими названиями и ценами,
как здесь  задать  значение которое дальше будет использоваться в контроллере и где правильнее всего хранить это значение (config, class property, env ...) ?

Иначе нужно будет в контроллере повторить весь код для получения именно этого значения.

Answer (score 0):

Если у вас есть какое-то константное значение к примеру "test" то путь такой:

1. Создаем в директории `config` новый файл, к примеру `orders.php`
2. Пишем в него следующий код:
   `<?php
   return [
    'test' => env('ORDERS_TEST') 
    ];`
3. В `.env` файле создаем переменую окружения `ORDERS_TEST="some value"`
4. В коде получаем это значение вот так: `config('orders.test)`